# I can't install unity for MacBook Pro by unity hub. This is log

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
{"level":"error","message":"Unhandled promise rejection, reason: Cannot create property 'headers' on boolean 'false'\n\tstack TypeError: Cannot create property 'headers' on boolean 'false'\n    at dispatchRequest (/Applications/Unity Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/axios/lib/core/dispatchRequest.js:34:18)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:86:5)","timestamp":"2021-08-18T15:07:04.383Z"}
{"moduleName":"front-end","level":"error","message":"[ '[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: tProvider <- t\\nhttps://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.10/$injector/unpr?p0=tProvider%20%3C-%20t',\n  'Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: tProvider <- t\\nhttps://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.10/$injector/unpr?p0=tProvider%20%3C-%20t\\n    at file:///Applications/Unity%20Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/client/dist/commons~main~newProject.js:33:676\\n    at file:///Applications/Unity%20Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/client/dist/commons~main~newProject.js:33:24197\\n    at Object.s [as get] (file:///Applications/Unity%20Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/client/dist/commons~main~newProject.js:33:25785)\\n    at file:///Applications/Unity%20Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/client/dist/commons~main~newProject.js:33:24282\\n    at s (file:///Applications/Unity%20Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/client/dist/commons~main~newProject.js:33:25785)\\n    at d (file:///Applications/Unity%20Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/client/dist/commons~main~newProject.js:33:26090)\\n    at Object.invoke (file:///Applications/Unity%20Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/client/dist/commons~main~newProject.js:33:26178)\\n    at C.instance (file:///Applications/Unity%20Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/client/dist/commons~main~newProject.js:33:58261)\\n    at r._createController (file:///Applications/Unity%20Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/client/dist/commons~main~newProject.js:52:29729)\\n    at Object.link (file:///Applications/Unity%20Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/client/dist/commons~main~newProject.js:52:29319)',\n  undefined ]","timestamp":"2021-08-18T15:09:21.850Z"}
{"moduleName":"LivePush","level":"error","message":"[ 'failed to check new notifications',\n  { Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND developer.unity.cn\n      at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:58:26)\n    errno: 'ENOTFOUND',\n    code: 'ENOTFOUND',\n    syscall: 'getaddrinfo',\n    hostname: 'developer.unity.cn',\n    config:\n     { adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],\n       transformRequest: [Object],\n       transformResponse: [Object],\n       timeout: 0,\n       xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',\n       xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',\n       maxContentLength: -1,\n       validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],\n       headers: [Object],\n       proxy: false,\n       method: 'get',\n       url:\n        'https://developer.unity.cn/api/notifications/MTIzNjk3Njk5MTU0Mjg=/hasUnread',\n       data: undefined },\n    request:\n     Writable {\n       _writableState: [WritableState],\n       writable: true,\n       _events: [Object],\n       _eventsCount: 2,\n       _maxListeners: undefined,\n       _options: [Object],\n       _redirectCount: 0,\n       _redirects: [],\n       _requestBodyLength: 0,\n       _requestBodyBuffers: [],\n       _onNativeResponse: [Function],\n       _currentRequest: [ClientRequest],\n       _currentUrl:\n        'https://developer.unity.cn/api/notifications/MTIzNjk3Njk5MTU0Mjg=/hasUnread' },\n    response: undefined } ]","timestamp":"2021-08-19T03:11:59.839Z"}
{"moduleName":"LivePush","level":"error","message":"[ 'fail to ge live pushes:',\n  { Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND connect.unity.cn\n      at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:58:26)\n    errno: 'ENOTFOUND',\n    code: 'ENOTFOUND',\n    syscall: 'getaddrinfo',\n    hostname: 'connect.unity.cn',\n    config:\n     { adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],\n       transformRequest: [Object],\n       transformResponse: [Object],\n       timeout: 0,\n       xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',\n       xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',\n       maxContentLength: -1,\n       validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],\n       headers: [Object],\n       proxy: false,\n       method: 'get',\n       params: [Object],\n       responseType: 'json',\n       url: 'https://connect.unity.cn/api/hub/livePush',\n       data: undefined },\n    request:\n     Writable {\n       _writableState: [WritableState],\n       writable: true,\n       _events: [Object],\n       _eventsCount: 2,\n       _maxListeners: undefined,\n       _options: [Object],\n       _redirectCount: 0,\n       _redirects: [],\n       _requestBodyLength: 0,\n       _requestBodyBuffers: [],\n       _onNativeResponse: [Function],\n       _currentRequest: [ClientRequest],\n       _currentUrl:\n        'https://connect.unity.cn/api/hub/livePush?userId=NWRiMjlkNjJlZGJjMmEwMDFmMjI5M2Fl' },\n    response: undefined } ]","timestamp":"2021-08-19T03:11:59.843Z"}
{"level":"error","message":"Unhandled promise rejection, reason: event is not defined\n\tstack ReferenceError: event is not defined\n    at App.<anonymous> (/Applications/Unity Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/build/app.js:337:13)\n    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)\n    at /Applications/Unity Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/build/app.js:7:71\n    at new Promise (<anonymous>)\n    at __awaiter (/Applications/Unity Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/build/app.js:3:12)\n    at WebContents.<anonymous> (/Applications/Unity Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/build/app.js:335:41)\n    at WebContents.emit (events.js:199:15)\n    at WebContents.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:469:20)\n    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Applications/Unity Hub.app/Contents/Resources/electron.asar/browser/guest-window-manager.js:252:16)\n    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:194:13)","timestamp":"2021-11-05T14:53:31.024Z"}
{"level":"error","message":"Unhandled promise rejection, reason: event is not defined\n\tstack ReferenceError: event is not defined\n    at App.<anonymous> (/Applications/Unity Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/build/app.js:337:13)\n    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)\n    at /Applications/Unity Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/build/app.js:7:71\n    at new Promise (<anonymous>)\n    at __awaiter (/Applications/Unity Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/build/app.js:3:12)\n    at WebContents.<anonymous> (/Applications/Unity Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/build/app.js:335:41)\n    at WebContents.emit (events.js:199:15)\n    at WebContents.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:469:20)\n    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Applications/Unity Hub.app/Contents/Resources/electron.asar/browser/guest-window-manager.js:252:16)\n    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:194:13)","timestamp":"2021-11-05T15:04:13.585Z"}
{"level":"error","message":"Unhandled promise rejection, reason: event is not defined\n\tstack ReferenceError: event is not defined\n    at App.<anonymous> (/Applications/Unity Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/build/app.js:337:13)\n    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)\n    at /Applications/Unity Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/build/app.js:7:71\n    at new Promise (<anonymous>)\n    at __awaiter (/Applications/Unity Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/build/app.js:3:12)\n    at WebContents.<anonymous> (/Applications/Unity Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/build/app.js:335:41)\n    at WebContents.emit (events.js:199:15)\n    at WebContents.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:469:20)\n    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Applications/Unity Hub.app/Contents/Resources/electron.asar/browser/guest-window-manager.js:252:16)\n    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:194:13)","timestamp":"2021-11-05T15:04:19.728Z"}
{"moduleName":"front-end","level":"error","message":"[ '[$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress\\nhttps://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.10/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply',\n  'Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress\\nhttps://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.10/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply\\n    at file:///Applications/Unity%20Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/client/dist/commons~main~newProject.js:33:676\\n    at g (file:///Applications/Unity%20Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/client/dist/commons~main~newProject.js:33:101547)\\n    at d.$apply (file:///Applications/Unity%20Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/client/dist/commons~main~newProject.js:33:100017)\\n    at file:///Applications/Unity%20Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/client/dist/main.js:9:115794\\n    at d.$emit (file:///Applications/Unity%20Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/client/dist/commons~main~newProject.js:33:100804)\\n    at e.removeEditorFromTheList (file:///Applications/Unity%20Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/client/dist/main.js:9:125563)\\n    at qe.cancelDownload (file:///Applications/Unity%20Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/client/dist/main.js:9:117957)\\n    at fn (eval at compile (file:///Applications/Unity%20Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/client/dist/commons~main~newProject.js:33:103035), <anonymous>:4:298)\\n    at i (file:///Applications/Unity%20Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/client/dist/commons~main~newProject.js:33:146090)\\n    at e.$eval (file:///Applications/Unity%20Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/client/dist/commons~main~newProject.js:33:99820)',\n  undefined ]","timestamp":"2021-11-05T15:36:49.211Z"}
{"moduleName":"front-end","level":"error","message":"[ '[$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress\\nhttps://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.10/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply',\n  'Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress\\nhttps://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.10/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply\\n    at file:///Applications/Unity%20Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/client/dist/commons~main~newProject.js:33:676\\n    at g (file:///Applications/Unity%20Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/client/dist/commons~main~newProject.js:33:101547)\\n    at d.$digest (file:///Applications/Unity%20Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/client/dist/commons~main~newProject.js:33:97783)\\n    at d.$apply (file:///Applications/Unity%20Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/client/dist/commons~main~newProject.js:33:100095)\\n    at file:///Applications/Unity%20Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/client/dist/main.js:9:115794\\n    at d.$emit (file:///Applications/Unity%20Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/client/dist/commons~main~newProject.js:33:100804)\\n    at e.removeEditorFromTheList (file:///Applications/Unity%20Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/client/dist/main.js:9:125563)\\n    at qe.cancelDownload (file:///Applications/Unity%20Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/client/dist/main.js:9:117957)\\n    at fn (eval at compile (file:///Applications/Unity%20Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/client/dist/commons~main~newProject.js:33:103035), <anonymous>:4:298)\\n    at i (file:///Applications/Unity%20Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/client/dist/commons~main~newProject.js:33:146090)',\n  undefined ]","timestamp":"2021-11-05T15:36:49.212Z"}
{"moduleName":"front-end","level":"error","message":"[ '[$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress\\nhttps://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.10/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply',\n  'Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress\\nhttps://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.10/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24apply\\n    at file:///Applications/Unity%20Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/client/dist/commons~main~newProject.js:33:676\\n    at g (file:///Applications/Unity%20Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/client/dist/commons~main~newProject.js:33:101547)\\n    at d.$digest (file:///Applications/Unity%20Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/client/dist/commons~main~newProject.js:33:97783)\\n    at d.$apply (file:///Applications/Unity%20Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/client/dist/commons~main~newProject.js:33:100095)\\n    at file:///Applications/Unity%20Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/client/dist/main.js:9:115794\\n    at d.$emit (file:///Applications/Unity%20Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/client/dist/commons~main~newProject.js:33:100804)\\n    at e.removeEditorFromTheList (file:///Applications/Unity%20Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/client/dist/main.js:9:125563)\\n    at qe.cancelDownload (file:///Applications/Unity%20Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/client/dist/main.js:9:117957)\\n    at fn (eval at compile (file:///Applications/Unity%20Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/client/dist/commons~main~newProject.js:33:103035), <anonymous>:4:298)\\n    at i (file:///Applications/Unity%20Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/client/dist/commons~main~newProject.js:33:146090)',\n  undefined ]","timestamp":"2021-11-05T15:36:49.213Z"}
{"level":"error","message":"Unhandled promise rejection, reason: event is not defined\n\tstack ReferenceError: event is not defined\n    at App.<anonymous> (/Applications/Unity Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/build/app.js:337:13)\n    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)\n    at /Applications/Unity Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/build/app.js:7:71\n    at new Promise (<anonymous>)\n    at __awaiter (/Applications/Unity Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/build/app.js:3:12)\n    at WebContents.<anonymous> (/Applications/Unity Hub.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/build/app.js:335:41)\n    at WebContents.emit (events.js:199:15)\n    at WebContents.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:469:20)\n    at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Applications/Unity Hub.app/Contents/Resources/electron.asar/browser/guest-window-manager.js:252:16)\n    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:194:13)","timestamp":"2021-11-05T15:37:00.080Z"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the Hub. Especially on a Mac. It's a borked idea with nefarious objectives - at best.

You can go here, and download the installer and support content, individually and independently, per version you need:

https://unity3d.com/get-unity/download/archive

BUT, you must click on the "Release Notes" button to get to the page with the actual Editor Installer, not a mere "installer Downloader" thing, that's also a complete waste of your time.

Latest, as of this moment are here...

-- 2021.2 (beta) https://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/2021.2.1

-- 2020.LTS: https://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/2020.3.22

-- 2019.LTS: https://unity3d.com/unity/whats-new/2019.4.32